# How can I by using the FormHelper ,or some other method, render an image link that runs javascript when clicked?

Tags: cakephp

Background:

I want to render this:

```
<a href="javascript:myfunction('Somevar')"><img src="some.png" width="20" height="20" border="0" /></a>
```

in a cakephp app.  Note: this link is not associated with a model at all, it's just part of a form going off-site.

I'm unsure of how to proceed:  I've seen [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/835/image) on the cakephp site, but 
with all that goes on in cake, I'm not sure about the whole javascript calling business. What's the best way to create such a thing?

EDIT: Cake 1.2 is what I am working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no problem at all to pass a Javascript function as the second parameter to `HtmlHelper::link`. This should do the trick:

```
echo $html->link(
    $html->image('some.png'),
    "javascript:myfunction('Somevar')",
    array('escape'=>false)
);
```

This invokes `HtmlHelper::link`, passing an image (generated by `HtmlHelper::image`) as the HTML around which to wrap the `<a />`, the Javascript function as the link's action, and informing Cake not to escape the HTML you passed.

**Update:**
Here's the snippet for Cake 1.2:

```
echo $html->link(
    $html->image('some.png'),
    "javascript:myfunction('Somevar')",
    null, null, false
);
```

The final `false` parameter of `HtmlHelper::link` instructs Cake not to escape the HTML.

Comment: I've edited this question. I'm using cake 1.2, which I should have specified.

Comment: And I've edited my answer to provide a code snippet for 1.2! HTH